# My modal keeps eating memory

Tags: ios, ios5, animation, automatic-ref-counting

I am experiencing a rather serious issue with my iPhone app using ARC.

I have a viewcontroller (lets call this A). This viewcontroller opens a navigationcontroller as a modal which runs through 3 different viewcontrollers (lets call these 1, 2 and 3). After viewing number 3 the navigationcontroller closes and we're back to A again.

So the flow is: A opens navigationcontroller and goes through 1->2->3 and then it closes again.

Every time I go through this flow i lose memory. I've searched through all my files looking for any retain og strong properties, un-invalidated timers or similar in order to solve this problem.

I have one idea, which might be the problem. At viewcontroller 1 i present a animation using coreanimation and a sprite. I'm using a implementation made by someone else. It seems like if i disable the animations the memory used seems quite constant (and thereby no memory loss). I have modified the implementation a bit to use ARC. This is the implementation I use for my sprite animations:

**`MCSpriteLayer.h`**

```
//
//  MCSpriteLayer.h
//
//  Created by Miguel Angel Friginal on 8/20/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Mystery Coconut Games. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MCSpriteLayer : CALayer {
    unsigned int sampleIndex;
}

// SampleIndex needs to be > 0
@property (nonatomic) unsigned int sampleIndex; 

// For use with sample rects set by the delegate
+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;
- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;

// If all samples are the same size 
+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size :(int)useRetina;
- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;

// Use this method instead of sprite.sampleIndex to obtain the index currently displayed on screen
- (unsigned int)currentSampleIndex; 


@end
```

**`MCSpriteLayer.m`**

```
//
//  MCSpriteLayer.m
//
//  Created by Miguel Angel Friginal on 8/20/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Mystery Coconut Games. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MCSpriteLayer.h"


@implementation MCSpriteLayer

@synthesize sampleIndex;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization, variable sample size


- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.contents = (__bridge id)img;
        sampleIndex = 1;
    }

    return self;
}


+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;
{
    MCSpriteLayer *layer = [(MCSpriteLayer*)[self alloc] initWithImage:img];
    return layer;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization, fixed sample size


- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;
{
    self = [self initWithImage:img];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        CGSize sampleSizeNormalized = CGSizeMake(size.width/CGImageGetWidth(img), size.height/CGImageGetHeight(img));
        self.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, size.width, size.height );
        self.contentsRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, sampleSizeNormalized.width, sampleSizeNormalized.height );
    }

    return self;
}


+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size :(int)useRetina;
{

    CGSize newSampleSize;
    if(useRetina == 1) {
        // Supporting retina displays
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
            ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
            newSampleSize = CGSizeMake(size.width*2, size.height*2);
        } else {
            newSampleSize = size;

        }
    } else
        newSampleSize = size;

    MCSpriteLayer *layer = [[self alloc] initWithImage:img sampleSize:newSampleSize];
    return layer;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Frame by frame animation


+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key;
{
    return [key isEqualToString:@"sampleIndex"];
}


// contentsRect or bounds changes are not animated
+ (id < CAAction >)defaultActionForKey:(NSString *)aKey;
{
    if ([aKey isEqualToString:@"contentsRect"] || [aKey isEqualToString:@"bounds"])
        return (id < CAAction >)[NSNull null];

    return [super defaultActionForKey:aKey];
}


- (unsigned int)currentSampleIndex;
{
    return ((MCSpriteLayer*)[self presentationLayer]).sampleIndex;
}


// Implement displayLayer: on the delegate to override how sample rectangles are calculated; remember to use currentSampleIndex, ignore sampleIndex == 0, and set the layer's bounds
- (void)display;
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLayer:)])
    {
        [self.delegate displayLayer:self];
        return;
    }

    unsigned int currentSampleIndex = [self currentSampleIndex];
    if (!currentSampleIndex)
        return;

    CGSize sampleSize = self.contentsRect.size;
    self.contentsRect = CGRectMake(
        ((currentSampleIndex - 1) % (int)(1/sampleSize.width)) * sampleSize.width, 
        ((currentSampleIndex - 1) / (int)(1/sampleSize.width)) * sampleSize.height, 
        sampleSize.width, sampleSize.height
    );
}


@end
```

Is this implementation somehow not realeasing correctly or retaining anything? Thanks in advance.

**Update**
- I am using Instruments to measure the memory. I am using the Memory Monitor where I keep an eye on the Physical Memory Free
- The image is created like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"round_start.png" ofType:nil];
CGSize fixedSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
mascot = [MCSpriteLayer layerWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path].CGImage sampleSize:fixedSize :0];
mascot.frame = CGRectMake(ANIMATION_X, ANIMATION_Y, ANIMATION_WIDTH, ANIMATION_HEIGHT);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:mascot2];

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sampleIndex"];
anim.delegate = self;
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:52];
anim.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;
anim.repeatCount = 1;

[mascot addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

- I've been experiencing with closing the modal with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: How are you tracking memory usage? Are you using Instruments? This is usually the best way to see what's taking memory. If you do that always make sure the Zombies are disabled.

Comment: How is the image created before passing to this class and what happens to it afterwards?

Comment: "After viewing number 3 the navigationcontroller closes and we're back to A again" -- how are you "closing" the navigation controller?

Comment: It's a good idea (I'd say essential if you weren't using ARC) to run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu) and it may identify issues for you. If you don't get a clean bill of health there, fix those issues first. I'd then run the app through the "Leaks" tool in Instruments ("Profile" on the "Product" menu) and you can use that to identify what objects are being allocated and not being released.

Comment: Already did this. Analyze returns no error and "Leaks" tool in Instruments shows no leaks. I've been struggling with this problem for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismissing the navigation controller does not release it, assuming you have a strong reference to it (that would need to get nil'd). In the view controllers used by it, add a log message in the dealloc method, so you know they are getting dealloced (you can do this for any subclassed item). If needed you can create a simple UINavigation subclass for the sole purpose of adding a message in dealloc). You will find that one or more of these items are not getting dealloced, and then you need to figure out if they are retained by a property/ivar or because they still have a superview.

Comment: After adding log messages to viewcontroller 1, 2 and 3 I noticed that only 1 and 3 called dealloc. Now how do i figure out what's making it not deallocating? I have not strong references.

Comment: Did the above help or was it something else? Inquiring minds want to know :-)